# MUST Share Personal Info with Windows 10?

Tags: privacy, windows-10

Just upgraded to windows 10. Had window open in Firefox when I upgraded. Should point out that for some reason Windows 10 would not upgrade on it's own, I went to Microsoft and they used remote assistance to upgrade. I then opened Firefox and this massage came up immediately:

```
        " Microsoft Edge Protection Warning

       Edge does not yet allow browser extensions
     which enable McAffe to protect your personal
     information and identity.


      We recommend using Internet Explorer so
    McAffe can continue protecting you. To help
    you, we'll unpin Edge from your task bar and
    pin Internet Explorer."
```

Wow,I can't protect my personal info? There can't be any privacy at all. Do I have to use their browser? My Firefox is working right now, worried it won't if I shut it down.Are all browsers like that?

Comment: That's just a scare tactic form McAfee. You shouldn't need browser extensions (they're very nice though, which is why my default browser is chrome), but if you do, just use a browser that supports it. Only Edge doesn't allow extensions. A step back, but at least there's an adblocker.

Comment: That's not a message from Firefox. It's from Microsoft Edge.

Comment: See [Mcafee's answer](https://community.mcafee.com/thread/86783)

Comment: McAfee has some kind of feature, which that call personal information protection. I don't know what it does exactly, but that's what they call it. That feature does not work with Edge. That's all this message is saying. It is not saying you have no privacy. It is not saying your browser is broken.

Comment: By the way, why are you using McAfee?

Comment: @Alpha3031   As an Edge user/tester, actually it's worse than that: there *isn't* even an adblocker.   And believe me, Windows testers are letting Microsoft know loudly and frequently that that in particular is a big, big shortfall (along with any lack of password manager support).  There is some speculation that MS will have to roll out some sort of built-in adblocker functionality before it finally gets extensions in the product next year, but speculation is all it is at this point.

Comment: @halfinformed Must have confused it with iOS 9 or something. Extensions in Chrome aren't working properly either, and it's not just windows 10. Just need to click on the icon though.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the message isn't from Microsoft Edge; it's from McAfee itself. But you needn't worry: Firefox (and your other browsers) aren't going anywhere.

What's really happening here? Well, Windows 10 makes the new Microsoft Edge browser, rather than Internet Explorer, the new default browser in the operating system. Edge has some promise to it as a new option in the browser arena (especially when it comes to [security](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/05/11/microsoft-edge-building-a-safer-browser/)).  Unfortunately, at this early point in its lifespan Edge isn't...well, to be blunt Microsoft shipped Edge and made it the default browser in Windows 10 despite the fact that it isn't fully baked yet.  One aspect of that: [Edge doesn't yet support extensions, and won't until some time in 2016.](http://www.theverge.com/2015/10/22/9596298/microsoft-edge-extensions-support-2016-release-update)

And that brings us to why McAfee wants you to not use Edge; to do what it purports to do McAfee needs to run a browser extension in whatever browser you happen to be using.  And since Microsoft Edge doesn't support extensions yet, McAfee needs you to stay away from using Edge or it won't be able to "protect your privacy" while you're browsing.  Thus, the attempt to kick Edge out of your taskbar and do the other things described.

Really, though, it sounds like what you really want to do is to restore Firefox as your default browser, rather than use either Edge *or* Internet Explorer. Fortunately, [you can do this pretty easily](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/make-firefox-your-default-browser).

(Postscript:
BTW, I'm writing this answer in Edge. It definitely has its appeal--the security improvements *are* quite interesting, and in some ways it's the fastest browser I've ever used.  As a Windows Insider tester I'm probably using it for about half my day-to-day browsing at this point, which I say only to show I don't hold Edge in any kind of enmity whatsoever. But at the same time right now it is undeniably still very, very raw.)